# How to install PyQt5 or PySide6 or any Qt Python Package

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside6

Using pyqt5-5.15.6 and Python 3.9.1

I've tried both:

```
pip install pyqt5 pyqt5-plugins
```

and

```
pip install pyside6
```

I've tried to set the environment variables:

```
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = r'...venv\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins'
os.environ['QTWEBENGINEPROCESS_PATH'] = r'...venv\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\bin'
```

No matter what package I install or what I do to try to fix the problem, there is always another error.

First it was:

```
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized
```

And then:

```
"qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in """
```

And then:

```
"Could not find QtWebEngineProcess.exe"
```

And then:

```
[0107/091432.763:ERROR:icu_util.cc(251)] Couldn't mmap icu data file
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled packages in different combinations trying to get this to work.
Is Qt just not a stable package? Or is there some extra step I'm missing?

Comment: Does python3 -m pip install pyqt5 pyqt5-plugins and similarly on the other library yield any benefit? Also, what is the specific code you are trying to run that is leading to these results?